# Can that clause be a complement?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Does the following sentence make sense?

> The origin of the festival is that people prayed for good weather.

Can that-clause be a complement?

Comment: It might be if it made any sense.

Comment: I'd probably "backshift" and switch to a ***noun / gerund*** phrase: *The origin of the festival **was** people **praying** for good weather.* But syntactically, your version is fine.